# Как с помощью Controller.Json в .NET Core сериализовать Dictionary<string, мой_тип> в JSON?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core

Есть словарь, в котором ключи – строки, а значения – объекты моего собственного класса. Необходимо превратить это в JSON на .NET Core. Посоветовали `Controller.Json`, но как им пользоваться не сказали. Рад буду любому варианту, применимому в .NET Core.

Примечание: всё прекрасно сериализуется с помощью `JavaScriptSerializer`, но нужна кроссплатформенность.

Comment: тут почитайте https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Как я понимаю, это не MVC, а Web API? Тогда используйте класс [JsonResult](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2)